# Minidump - viewing content of memory address

Tags: minidumps, windbg

I have a Windows 10 minidump with this opening text (viewed in WinDbg):

> KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (1e)
> This is a very common BugCheck.  **Usually the exception address pinpoints
>
> the driver/function that caused the problem.**  Always note this address
> as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
> Arguments:
> Arg1: ffffffffc0000005, The exception code that was not handled
> Arg2: fffff805068027f6, The address that the exception occurred at
> Arg3: 0000000000000000, Parameter 0 of the exception
> Arg4: ffffffffffffffff, Parameter 1 of the exception

Let's say I wanted to investigate the exception address to find out if there is indeed information about a driver or a function there: **How do I go about it?**

I've tried various formats of the `d`, `dd`, `ds` and so forth, but it either gives me `?????` or some other type of gibberish, for example:

> 9: kd> dW fffff805068027f6
> fffff805`068027f6  8b48 2040 3b4c 0fc0 9384 0000 7200 0f2a  H.@ L;.......r*.

It feels like I'm missing something rudimentary, and though I've googled extensively I can't really figure out where I'm even lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be far simpler to use the free
[BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html),
which does the analysis work for you:

[image]